# How to programmatically change a page's meta tag?

Tags: development, gantry, metadata

I am making a very simple product page for my site. With very little component development experience, I decided to build this page with Javascript only. The URLs will be like https://mystie.com/product?id=13367, where I use Javascript to get the product info from an outside JSON api:

```
$.get('https://jsonapi.url/?id=13367',function(product){
   displayProductPage(product)
})
```

For this page I use [gantry's custom page](https://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/configure/menu-item) and put a custom module on it, the function `displayProductPage` will render html for the product and append it to the custom module.

It's after I finished the html/css/javascript part when I realized I had missed one important thing: I need to set the meta tags according to the product id: og:image, og:description etc., so when people share the page Facebook will get the correct info of the product.

I've asked the same question in [Gantry's github page](https://github.com/gantry/gantry5/issues/2919) but haven't got it solved yet.

So far, I've been able to find the PHP code to set the meta tag, I believe it's as simple as

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData('og:title', $link_title);
```

I just don't know where to put these codes in my project.

PS: One quickest and simplest solution might be just put the PHP code in the custom module but I've never done that before. While waiting for answers I will be going through this option.